# Progressive Crawling of Tweets

Tags: php, twitter

In Twitter APIs, how do I do progressive crawling of tweets? For e.g. using the search API:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q='.urlencode("#thanksgiving").'&count=100'.'&tweet_mode=extended';
```

The max return is 100 tweets. But there are more than 100 tweets, now how do I specify to get the next 100 tweets? And is it, time dependent? Meaning the first time the latest 100 tweets are returned?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a feature offered by the Standard Search API.

Using [the Premium search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search):

> To request the next 'page' of data, you must make the exact same query as the original, including query, toDate, and fromDate, if used, and also include a 'next' request parameter set to the value from the previous response. This can be utilized with either a GET or POST request. However, the 'next' parameter must be URL encoded in the case of a GET request. You can continue to pass in the 'next' element from your previous query until you have received all Tweets from the time period covered by your query. When you receive a response that does not include a 'next' element, it means that you have reached the last page and no additional data are available for the specified query and time range.

Since you are passing a `next` parameter, it doesn't matter if newer data appears in front of the data you've already processed.